# Form displays blank fields instead of DB data values

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a from with a plugin that updates a record in the DB. I see the updated data in the record in the DB, but when i load the form the updated data does not show.
there are no business rules, the is no JS OnLoad event.
The record is inactive in the DB when the data is updated, but i don' think that should matter
Any ideas as to what I am overlooking?

Comment: Do you see anything in console errors etc?

Comment: some screenshots of form field vs DB will help. you can mask any critical info.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the changes should still save to an inactive record.

Under Advanced Settings > Administration > System Settings > Customization you can set "Enable logging to plug-in trace log" to "All".

Then in the plugin you can use the [ITracingService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/best-practices/business-logic/use-itracingservice-plugins) to log messages, which are then visible in Advanced Settings > Plugin-In Trace Log.

You could log the fields' values before and after you set them to confirm that they're getting set.

Or, for a "quick and dirty" option store the fields' values before you set them, then after you set them, throw an [InvalidPluginExecution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/best-practices/business-logic/use-invalidpluginexecutionexception-plugin-workflow-activities) exception containing the "before and after" values. The exception message will pop up right in the UI.

We'd be better able to analyze the issue if you post your code.

On a related note, when writing plugins I often separate the logic out into a Visual Studio Shared Project. I reference that project from a console app and the plugin assembly. The console app enables me to test and debug locally with full VS debugging capabilities before publishing the plugin. Of course there are certain things from the context that can be tricky to mock in the Console app, so your mileage may vary depending on the application.

There are also testing frameworks like FakeXrmEasy, but I have yet to try any of those.